# Why is this codes output an Error?

Tags: php, html

I am a newbie on php writing. In the my first trying, I get a problem on input a html tag to php.

This code output an error:

```
<?php
$a="Begin";
$b=12;
echo $b . " " . $a . " " . "This is php file <br/>";
echo strlen($a);
echo strpos($a,"in") . "<br/>";
echo addcslashes($a,"i")";
?>
```

this is the error message I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/specials/public_html/bextool.com/1.php on line 7
```

Is there any body who can explain about it?

Comment: So you weren't able to check 4 lines of code for a parse error? You should give up now.

Comment: Its clearly written that " is unexpected there and is expecting , or ; in line number 7.

Comment: @Ari, you have extra `"` at the last line! Last line must look like this: `echo addcslashes($a,"i");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
echo addcslashes($a,"i")";
```

should be

```
echo addcslashes($a,"i");
```

You can sometimes tell in the editor that the colors are different when you're missing a `"` or something.  In this case, you can see the last semicolon is not black, like the other ones - a sign of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

remove the last `"` in line number 7 and make it like this:

```
echo addcslashes($a,"i");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the one extra double quote `"`

```
echo addcslashes($a,"i")";
```

Make it

```
echo addcslashes($a,"i");
```